# ReportLab variable nextPageTemplate's

Tags: python, reportlab

I am in the process of converting the database from pfaf.org (plant for a future) into a pdf book.
I have hit a bit of a stumbling block regarding pageTemplates.

Each plant may begin on a left or a right aligned page; and may potentially be two or more pages.
I have two templates for the first plant page (left and right) and also two more templates for the potential subsequent pages.

Currently this is handled as follows (for instance):

```
for i, plant in enumerate(plants):
  #the first plant is printed on a right-hand page
  if i % 2 == 0:
    template = 'left'
    second = 'right'
  else:
    template = 'right'
    second = 'left'

  Story.append(nextPageTemplate(template,'*', 'secondary_'+template, 'secondary_'+second))
  Story.append(PageBreak())
  #append various paragraphs, jumping between frames, etc...
```

The code (as you can probably tell) works fine for single page plants.
It also works (semi) as expected for multi page plants.

However, as you can also probably see, a two (or four,etc) page plant will break the template arrangement, because the above code assumes page position based upon plant number, rather than page number.

I can't see a solution for this in the location of the code above (i.e during the Story.append cycle) - as at that point I can not tell whether the plant has used more than one page, and thus what page I am currently on, as such.

I hoped that I could perhaps tweak the nextPageTemplate structure from my custom docTemplate, but I can't figure out if this is possible.

Is it? Or is there another solution? Would really appreciate any help. Have been reading all over, but the best examples I can find don't quite cover this scenario.

Any questions, please ask.
Thank you

---

Thank you, Nitzle:
The trouble is that I don't know how many pages each plant will take up.
For instance - a new plant starts on an odd page so I give it a cycle of templates ('right', '*', 'secondaryLeft', 'secondaryRight'). [the secondary pages are just a single frame with appropriate margin.]

If that plant is one page long, no problem, the next plant will have the template cycle opposite to the above.
However, if the plant has, say, two pages, it will cause the following plant to fall again on an odd page again and thus the template cycle should not change... I hope this makes sense.

This is the circumstance I am having trouble solving...  If I do as you say, it doesn't allow for multiple page plants. Most of my code is as follows; I have tried to slim it down a little though :) hopefully it still contains all relevant stuff and not too much unnecessary.

```
import os
import sys
import MySQLdb

from reportlab.platypus import Spacer, Image, Table, TableStyle, PageBreak, FrameBreak, paraparser
from reportlab.platypus.doctemplate import BaseDocTemplate, PageTemplate, NextPageTemplate, _doNothing
from reportlab.platypus.tableofcontents import TableOfContents
from reportlab.platypus.frames import Frame
from reportlab.platypus.flowables import KeepInFrame
from reportlab.platypus.paragraph import Paragraph

from reportlab.lib.units import mm, cm
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, A5
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_CENTER, TA_RIGHT
from reportlab.lib.styles import StyleSheet1, ParagraphStyle as PS
from reportlab.lib import colors

from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing, Rect, String

from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import registerFont, stringWidth
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.rl_config import warnOnMissingFontGlyphs
warnOnMissingFontGlyphs = 0

registerFont(TTFont('Museo_', '/home/wuwei/.fonts/Museo300-Regular.ttf'))
registerFont(TTFont('Museo_M', '/home/wuwei/.fonts/Museo500-Regular.ttf'))
registerFont(TTFont('Trebuchet', '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf'))
registerFont(TTFont('Trebuchet_I', '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Trebuchet_MS_Italic.ttf'))

## SOME VARIABLE DEFINITIONS ##

titleFont = "Museo_M"
subtitleFont = "Museo_"
stdFont = "Trebuchet"
stdItalic = "Trebuchet_I"
#stdSize = 14

"""CREATE GLOBALS"""
_w, _h = A4
_head_w = 17.5*cm
_head_pad = 0.2*cm
_main_w = 17.2*cm
_budge = 0.3*cm

_left_margin = 1.5*cm
_right_margin = 2.0*cm
_top_margin = 1.5*cm
_bottom_margin = 2.0*cm

_latinFontS = 18

#reset superFraction to style 'common name' placement
paraparser.superFraction = 0.15
paraparser.sizeDelta = 0


###########################################################################################################
#########################################                   ###############################################
########################################     DB FUNCTIONS     #############################################
#########################################                   ###############################################
###########################################################################################################

def connectToDB():
    try:
        connection = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", 
                                user = "root", 
                                passwd = "****************", 
                                db = "pfaf")
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        print "I guess, either you don't have a local copy of the pfaf db"
        print "or something is wrong with your connection details."
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
        sys.exit (1)

    return connection

def close(item, exit=0):
    #used to close both database cursors and connections
    item.close()
    if exit == 1:
        sys.exit (0)

def runQuery(q, conn):
    results = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    results.execute (q)
    return results

def Fetch(results, fetchAll=0):
    if fetchAll:
        print "fetchAll"
        # FETCHALL option:
        rows = results.fetchall()
        #cursor.close()
        #conn.close()
        '''for row in rows:
            print "%s, %s" % (row["Latin Name"], row["Hardyness"])
        print "%d rows were returned" % results.rowcount'''
        return rows
    else:
        # FETCHONE option: 
        ##--- Print some debug info to command line ---##
        print "Latin Name  -  Common Name  -  Hardyness"       
        while (1):
            row = results.fetchone()
            if row == None:
                break

            latin_name = row["Latin Name"]
            common_name = row["Common name"]
            hardyness = row["Hardyness"]
            family = row["Family"]
            synonyms = row["Synonyms"]

        ##--- Print some more useful debug info to command line ---##
            print "%s  -  %s  -  %s" % (latin_name, common_name, hardyness)
        print row

        if results.rowcount != 1:
            print "%d rows were returned" % results.rowcount
        else:
            print "%d row was returned" % results.rowcount

        return row


###########################################################################################################
#########################################                   ###############################################
########################################  STORY PROCESSING    #############################################
#########################################                   ###############################################
###########################################################################################################

def drawBorders(canv, side):
    canv.saveState()
    d = Drawing(0,0)

    #header border#
    r = Rect( side-_budge, _h-(2.4*cm), _head_w+(_budge*2), 1.2*cm, rx=5, ry=5 )
    r.strokeColor = colors.black
    r.fillColor = colors.white
    r.strokeWidth = 1.5
    d.add(r)

    #hardyness border#
    rad = 5
    hWidth = 1.4*cm
    if side == _left_margin:
        hPos = -rad
    else:
        hPos = _w - hWidth + rad
    r = Rect( hPos, _h-(3.8*cm), hWidth, 1.2*cm, rx=rad, ry=rad )
    r.strokeColor = colors.black
    r.fillColor = colors.white
    r.strokeWidth = 1.5
    d.add(r)

    d.drawOn(canv, 0, 0)
    canv.restoreState()

def drawFooter(canv, doc):
    canv.saveState()
    canv.setFont(stdFont,10)
    canv.drawCentredString((_w/2.0), 1.5*cm, "%d - %s" % (doc.page, doc.latinName))        
    canv.restoreState()


class LeftPageTemplate(PageTemplate):
    def __init__(self):
        #allow a bigger margin on the right for binding
        latinF =    Frame(_left_margin, 27.5*cm,  _head_w,  0.8*cm,     id='latinL',    showBoundary=0, 
                          rightPadding=0, leftPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)
        hardyF =    Frame(0.1*cm, 26.05*cm,   cm,  cm,  id='hardL',       showBoundary=0, 
                          rightPadding=0, leftPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)
        synF =      Frame(_left_margin, 26.65*cm,   _main_w,  0.55*cm,  id='synL',       showBoundary=0, 
                          rightPadding=0, leftPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)
        otherF =    Frame(_left_margin, 22.1*cm,   12.4*cm,  4.5*cm,  id='otherL',       showBoundary=1)
        calF =      Frame(14.2*cm, 22.1*cm,   4.5*cm,  4.5*cm,  id='calL',       showBoundary=0, 
                          rightPadding=0, leftPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)
        flowF =     Frame(_left_margin, 2.0*cm,   _main_w,  19.85*cm,  id='flowL',     showBoundary=1)

        PageTemplate.__init__(self,
                              id='left',
                              frames=[latinF, hardyF, synF, otherF, calF, flowF], 
                              pagesize=A4)

    def beforeDrawPage(self, canv, doc):
        drawBorders(canv, _left_margin)

    def afterDrawPage(self, canv, doc): 
        drawFooter(canv, doc)


class RightPageTemplate(PageTemplate):
    def __init__(self):
        #allow a bigger margin on the left for binding
        latinF =    Frame(_right_margin, 27.5*cm,  _head_w,  0.8*cm,     id='latinR',    showBoundary=0, 
                          rightPadding=0, leftPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)
        hardyF =    Frame(_w-1.1*cm, 26.05*cm,   cm,  cm,  id='hardR',       showBoundary=0, 
                          rightPadding=0, leftPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)
        synF =      Frame(_right_margin+_budge, 26.65*cm,   _main_w,  0.55*cm,  id='synR',       showBoundary=0, 
                          rightPadding=0, leftPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)
        calF =      Frame(_right_margin+_budge, 22.1*cm,   4.5*cm,  4.5*cm,  id='calR',       showBoundary=0, 
                          rightPadding=0, leftPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)
        otherF =    Frame(_right_margin+5.1*cm, 22.1*cm,   12.4*cm,  4.5*cm,  id='otherR',       showBoundary=1)
        flowF =     Frame(_right_margin+_budge, 2.0*cm,   _main_w,  19.85*cm,  id='flowR',     showBoundary=1)

        PageTemplate.__init__(self,
                              id='right',
                              frames=[latinF, hardyF, synF, otherF, calF, flowF], 
                              pagesize=A4)

    def beforeDrawPage(self, canv, doc):
        drawBorders(canv, _right_margin)

    def afterDrawPage(self, canv, doc):
        drawFooter(canv, doc)


class MyDocTemplate(BaseDocTemplate):
    _invalidInitArgs = ('pageTemplates',)

    def __init__(self, filename, **kw):
        self.allowSplitting = 0
        BaseDocTemplate.__init__(self, filename, **kw)

        self.latinName = "(none initially)"
        self.latinWidth = 0 #(none initially)

    def afterInit(self):
        self._calc() #in case we have changed margin sizes etc

        self.leftMargin = _left_margin
        self.rightMargin = _right_margin
        self.topMargin = _top_margin
        self.bottomMargin = _bottom_margin
        self.width = _w - self.leftMargin - self.rightMargin
        self.height = _h - self.topMargin - self.bottomMargin

        frameStd = Frame(cm, self.bottomMargin, (_w - 2*cm), (_h - 3*cm), id='cvr', showBoundary=0)
        frameToC = Frame(self.rightMargin, self.bottomMargin, self.width, self.height, id='tocFrame', showBoundary=0)
        frameL = Frame(self.leftMargin, self.bottomMargin, self.width, self.height, id='secLeftFrame', showBoundary=1)
        frameR = Frame(self.leftMargin, self.bottomMargin, self.width, self.height, id='secRightFrame', showBoundary=1)

        self.addPageTemplates( [PageTemplate(id='Cover', frames=frameStd, onPage=coverPage, pagesize=self.pagesize), 
                                PageTemplate(id='ToC', frames=frameToC, onPage=tocPage, pagesize=self.pagesize), 
                                PageTemplate(id='blank', frames=frameStd, onPage=_doNothing, pagesize=self.pagesize), 
                                LeftPageTemplate(), 
                                RightPageTemplate(),
                                PageTemplate(id='secondary_left', frames=frameL, onPage=_doNothing, pagesize=self.pagesize),
                                PageTemplate(id='secondary_right', frames=frameR, onPage=_doNothing, pagesize=self.pagesize)
                               ] )

    def afterFlowable(self, flowable):
        """Registers ToC entries - and captures latin name for footer"""
        if isinstance(flowable, Paragraph):
            style = flowable.style.name
            key = None
            firstWord = style.split('_',1)[0]
            if (style == 'LatinName') or (style == 'LatinNameR') or (firstWord == 'LatinName'):
                level = 0
                key = 'latin-%s' % self.seq.nextf('LatinName')
                self.canv.bookmarkPage(key)

                wholeStr = flowable.getPlainText()
                if self.page % 2 == 0: #even numbers are on left pages
                    latinOnly = wholeStr.split('\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0')[0] #looks for '&nbsp&nbsp' as divider
                else:
                    latinOnly = wholeStr.split('\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0')[1]
                self.latinName = latinOnly
                E = [level, latinOnly, self.page]
                if key is not None: E.append(key)
                self.notify('TOCEntry', tuple(E))
                '''elif (style == 'CommonName'):
                self.commonName = flowable.getPlainText()
                self.commonWidth = stringWidth(self.commonName, styles['common'].fontName, styles['common'].fontSize)'''
            else:
                return


""" coverPage and otherPages are intended for non-flowing (i.e standard) parts of the pages """
def coverPage(canvas, doc):
    Title = "Plants for a Future"
    pageinfo = "The full database collected as a printable book"
    canvas.setTitle(Title + " : " + pageinfo)

    print "creating cover page..."
    canvas.saveState()
    d = Drawing(0,0)

    r = Rect( 0, 0, 12*cm, 4*cm, rx=5, ry=5 )
    r.strokeColor = colors.black
    r.fillColor = colors.white
    r.strokeWidth = 3
    d.add(r)
    d.drawOn(canvas, (_w/2.0)-6*cm, _h-(6.2*cm))

    canvas.setFont(stdFont, 30)
    canvas.drawCentredString(_w/2.0, _h-108, Title)
    canvas.setFont(stdItalic, 14)
    canvas.drawCentredString(_w/2.0, _h-150, pageinfo)
    canvas.restoreState()

def tocPage(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setFont(stdFont,10)
    canvas.drawCentredString((_w/2.0), 1.5*cm, "Table of Contents")
    canvas.restoreState()


def getMedicinal(plant):
    p = plant
    initial = p["Medicinal"]
    return initial


""" Run after 'Story' has been fully populated """
def go():
    doc = MyDocTemplate('result01.pdf')
    passes = doc.multiBuild(Story)

########################################################################

"""Build StyleSheet"""
styles = buildStyle()

h1 = PS(name = 'HeadingOne',
        fontName = stdFont, 
        fontSize = 14,
        leading = 16)

h2 = PS(name = 'HeadingTwo',
        fontName = stdFont, 
        fontSize = 12,
        leading = 14,
        leftIndent = 1*cm)

Story=[]

a = Story.append
a(NextPageTemplate('blank'))
a(PageBreak())
a(NextPageTemplate('ToC'))
a(PageBreak())

toc = TableOfContents()
toc.levelStyles = [ h1, h2 ]
a(toc)

a(NextPageTemplate('blank'))
a(PageBreak())


"""###LEFT PAGES SHOULD BE STYLED RIGHT-ALIGNED, AND RIGHT PAGES LEFT-ALIGNED###"""
#print type(plants)
for i, plant in enumerate(plants):
    ### THIS INITIAL CHECK BREAKS AS IT NEEDS TO BE BASED ON PAGE NUMBER, NOT PLANT NUMBER!!! ###
    if i %2 == 0: #IF FIRST PLANT APPEARS ON A RIGHTSIDE PAGE, ELSE REVERSE THE R and L
        page='R'
        template = 'right'
        second = 'left'
    else:
        page='L'
        template ='left'
        second = 'right'

    #FIRST THINGS FIRST:
    #Make sure the page templates flow nicely for each plant "chapter"
    a(NextPageTemplate([template, '*', ('secondary_'+template), ('secondary_'+second) ]))
    a(PageBreak())

    '''CAPTURE PLANT INFO IN OBJECTS'''
    p = plant

    '''for info in plant:
        print info, p[info]'''


    '''Header'''
    latin = p["Latin Name"]
    common = p["Common name"]
    family = p["Family"]
    syn = p["Synonyms"]
    """X. congestum. (Lour.)Merrill.  X. racemosum. Miq.  Apactis japonica.  Croton congestum.  
                Flacourtia japonica. Walp.  Hisingera japonica.  H. racemosa."""
    hardy = str(p["Hardyness"])

    '''Basic Info'''
    author = p["Author"]
    botanicalrefs = p["Botanical references"]
    width = p["Width"]
    height = p["Height"]
    habit = p["Habit"]

    planttype = clean("Deciduous/Evergreen", p)

    plantrange = p["Range"]
    habitat = p["Habitat"]
    soil = clean("Soil", plant)
    shade = p["Shade"]
    moisture = p["Moisture"]
    drained = p["Well-drained"]
    nf = p["Nitrogen fixer"]
    pH = p["pH"]
    acid = p["Acid"]
    alkaline = p["Alkaline"]
    saline = p["Saline"]
    wind = p["Wind"]

    rate = clean("Growth rate", plant)
    pollution = p["Pollution"]
    poorsoil = p["Poor soil"]
    drought = p["Drought"]
    heavyclay = p["Heavy clay"]
    tender = clean("FrostTender", plant)

    inleaf = p["In leaf"]
    flowering = p["Flowering time"]
    seedripens = p["Seed ripens"]
    flowertype = p["Flower Type"]
    pollinators = p["Pollinators"]
    selffertile = clean("Self-fertile", plant)

    hazards = p["Known hazards"]

    rating_edible = p["Rating"]
    rating_med = p["Medicinal Rating"]
    edibleuses = p["Edible uses"]
    medicinaluses = getMedicinal(plant)
    otheruses = p["Uses notes"]
    #the following encoding allows for special characters such as degree symbol
    cultivation = unicode(p["Cultivation details"], 'latin-1')#'ISO-8859-1')
    propagation = p["Propagation 1"]

    scented = p["Scented"] #boolean - requires further lookup in `ScentedPlants` table

    string = '''%s is %s %s growing to %gm by %gm at a %s rate.<br/> 
                It's habitats are %s <br/><br/> Range: %s
                    <br/><br/>
                Suitable for %s soils. <br/><br/>
                Shade: %s, Moisture: %s <br/>
                Well-drained: %d, Nitrogen fixer: %d <br/> ph: %s <br/>
                Acid: %d, Alkaline: %d, Saline: %d <br/>
                Wind: %s 
                    <br/><br/>
                Author: %s <br/> Botanical References: %s''' % (
                    latin, planttype, habit.lower(), width, height, rate, 
                    habitat[0].lower()+habitat[1:], plantrange, 
                    soil, shade, moisture, drained,
                    nf, pH, acid, alkaline, saline, wind, author, botanicalrefs )
    string = unicode(string, 'latin-1')

    latinW = stringWidth(latin, styles['latin'].fontName, styles['latin'].fontSize)
    commonW = stringWidth(common, styles['common'].fontName, styles['common'].fontSize)

    if (latinW + commonW + (_head_pad*3)) > _head_w:
        styleName = "LatinName_" + str(i)
        latinStyle = PS( name=styleName, 
                         parent=styles['Normal'],
                         fontName=titleFont, 
                         fontSize=_latinFontS, 
                         leading=22, 
                         spaceAfter=0)
        j = 1
        #should the latin string be too long, attempt to shrink until it fits
        while (latinW + commonW + (_head_pad*3)) > _head_w:
            #change the font size until ok...
            latinStyle.fontSize = _latinFontS -j
            latinW = stringWidth(latin, latinStyle.fontName, latinStyle.fontSize)
            j += 0.2
    else:
        latinStyle = styles['LatinName']

    if page == 'L':
        headerText = '''<para align="left">
                            %s
                            <font face="%s" size="%d">&nbsp;&nbsp;<super>%s</super></font>
                        </para>''' % (latin, subtitleFont, 12, common)
    else:
        headerText = '''<para align="right">
                            <font face="%s" size="%d"><super>%s</super>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
                            %s
                        </para>''' % (subtitleFont, 12, common, latin)
    latinPara = Paragraph(headerText, latinStyle)

    a(FrameBreak('latin'+page))
    a(latinPara)

    a(FrameBreak('syn'+page))
    a(KeepInFrame(_main_w, 1.5*cm, 
                  [Paragraph(syn, styles['syn'+page])], 
                  mode="shrink")) #can be shrink, truncate or overflow

    a(FrameBreak('hard'+page))
    a(Paragraph(hardy, styles['hardy']))

    a(FrameBreak('cal'+page))
    #SHALL BE ULTIMATELY POPULATED VIA DATABASE#
    greyOut = [ [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0] ]

    cal = drawCalendar(greyOut)
    a(cal)

    a(FrameBreak('flow'+page))
    a(Paragraph(string, styles['Normal']))
    a(Paragraph("Edible Uses", styles['title']))
    a(Paragraph("Medicinal Uses", styles['title']))
    a(Paragraph("Other Uses", styles['title']))

    a(Paragraph("Cultivation", styles['title']))
    a(Paragraph(cultivation, styles['Normal']))

    a(Paragraph("Propagation", styles['title']))
    a(Paragraph(propagation, styles['Normal']))


##ASSEMBLE PDF###
go()
```

Comment: Short answer, you need to modify the function that determines the next page template to execute custom behavior based on the current page number, which you'll be able to get because it will be called during build. It's been a while so I don't recall the exact function you are looking for, but you can do it easily enough if you've created a custom document class.

Comment: thank you, Gordon - I shall explore this further

Comment: thanks, Will, for putting my "self-answer" into my original post - in future, should I just edit the post to make such an ammendment? (the reason I did as I did, was because it was obviously too long for a comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just switching between a "left" and a "right" template, you could try using the `_handle_nextPageTemplate` method of the `BaseDocTemplate` class. One way to keep track of page number would be to use the `afterPage` hook to increment a page number.

```
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate

class MyDocTemplate(BaseDocTemplate):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        BaseDocTemplate.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__pageNum = 1

    def afterPage(self):
        """Called after all flowables have been drawn on a page"""

        # Increment pageNum since the page has been completed
        self.__pageNum += 1

        # If the page number is even, force "left-side" template
        if self.__pageNum % 2 == 0:
            self._handle_nextPageTemplate('left_template')
        else:
            self._handle_nextPageTemplate('right_template')
```

I haven't tested the code above, but you may need to use `beforePage` instead depending on how it checks page template order.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon and Nitzle.

Comment: I have rambled a bit below, and attached more code. However, I am now thinking that if I j=keep track of what flowable is being rendered (and say have a boolean that lets me know if I am starting a new plant) then perhaps the perfect solution is to use _handle_nextPageTemplate() to append the cycle :)

Comment: @berilac If you need to keep track of what flowable is being rendered, you can use the `afterFlowable` method of `BaseDocTemplate` and then use `_handle_nextPageTemplate`.